# Change Column names of AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, abstracttablemodel

Is it possible to change AbstractTableModel column names dynamically?

I am trying to implement **setColumnName(0, "Speed rpm")** method.

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private String[] columnNames = {"Speed", "Pressure",
    "Force"};
public ArrayList<Values> list;

public MyModel() {

    list = new ArrayList<Values>();
}

public void setColumnName(int i, String name) {
    columnNames[i,name];
}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: `columnNames[i] =name;`

Comment: +1 @nachokk, thanks. it worked. Could you answer it, so i can vote it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public void setColumnName(int i, String name) {
    columnNames[i,name];
}
```

to

```
public void setColumnName(int i, String name) {
    columnNames[i] = name;
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

Following (always)good advices from @camickr

> Invoking the fireTableStructureChanged() method will cause all custom
>   renderers/editors to be lost. You can use the
>   table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(..) method when you create the
>   table to prevent this from happening

Comment: AFAIK, a TableModelEvent will also have to be fired to notify the view that the header row has been changed.

Comment: invoking the fireTableStructureChanged() method will cause all custom renderers/editors to be lost.

Comment: @camickr i see then `AbstractTableModel` doesn't provide any method to notfiy that only a column name change

Comment: Yes, I was just providing a warning to the OP that by using that method the table is recreated which means the renderer/editors are lost and the table columns are reordered back to their original state and any sorting of the data in the table is lost. You can use the `table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(..)` method when you create the table to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @camickr I didn't know that, thanks camickr i added to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Change the TableColumn:

```
tableColumn.setHeaderValue(...);
table.getTableHeader().repaint();
```

You can get the TableColumn by using:

```
table.getColumn(...); // or
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(...);
```

Comment: +1 for alternative solution not using what op provide :)